# Swift adding view above keyboard getting Error Cannot assign to property: 'inputAccessoryView' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to add UIView on top of the keyboard for toolbar. here, I am using below code for growing textview

https://github.com/muukii/NextGrowingTextView

I added additionally UIView in Viewcontroller top side and added below code into Viewcontroller

```
@IBOutlet var toolBarView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var growingTextView: NextGrowingTextView!
```

in ViewDidLoad() added below line

```
self.growingTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolBarView
```

I am getting below error, how to fix this?

> Cannot assign to property: 'inputAccessoryView' is a get-only property

If I add below line

```
self.growingTextView.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBarView
```

I am getting output like below screen in iPhone X series (Other devices working fine).

[current output getting gap between toolbarview and growingTextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKM4s.png)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How to fix that error? @AlexandrKolesnik

Comment: create container put inside your toolbar and growingTextView, you can't change read-only property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: The error occurs because class `NextGrowingTextView` is of type `UIScrollView` and you simply cannot change a scroll view's  `inputAccessoryView`. You can see that in NextGrowingTextView.swift.

You should - though - be able to modify `self.growingTextView.textView.inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: thanks your answer working for me but I am getting gap between growingTextView and toolbarview. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like insufficient layouting... What does your toolBarView look like and how do you layout its subviews? Also take a look at the element inspector to see where that gap could come from.

Comment: I checked its not insufficient layout issue. Something wrong. @Muli

Comment: How am I supposed to help you with this? You have to provide some information like screenshot, frame rectangles, ... Maybe NextGrowingTextView's author doesn't even want you to do that.

Comment: sorry @Muli. I updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: Try to set your custom view's frame to its superview's bounds. Then it should at least fill the space. next step could be to decrease your superview's frame so that not too much space's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You've to use

```
self.growingTextView.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBarView
```

instead of

```
self.growingTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolBarView
```

Because `growingTextView` is a **object instance** of `NextGrowingTextView` which is subClass of `UIScrollView` and in this for `textView` used `NextGrowingInternalTextView`.